# Habilitar puerto en Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn

Estoy trabajando con python y heroku en un tipo de aplicación "web", y debo recibir datos provenientes de un dispositivo remoto el cual los enviá por un puerto especifico.

Buscando por internet encontré que configurando las "config var" se puede configurar el puerto, pero no me funciona de ese modo (configure -> PORT = 4874).

Por ejemplo envió lo siguiente: mijxj92web.herokuapp.com:4874/ ..... heroku no reacciona.

Quizás es tipo de aplicación "web" no se puede cambiar el tipo de puerto y deba trabajar con un tipo de aplicación "worker" o simplemente lo que deseo hacer no se puede realizar en la plataforma heroku.

Cualquier ayuda me sera de utilidad.

Comment: podrias agregar el puerto al entorno virtual de heroku algo como esto: heroku config:add PORT=4874

Comment: He agregado el comando mencionado  y aplique el mismo ejemplo, y aun no me funciona. @DiegoAvila Te ha funcionado de esa forma??